# using '1' instead of user_id as second parameter to belongsTo

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have this situation where I want (hope/wish) to use a particular number e.g 1 directly as second parameter instead of using user_id. I was wondering if there was a to achieve this? or is it just not possible?

For example, currently I have relationship like this.

```
class orders extends Model
{
     protected $tableName = 'orders';
     protected $primarykey = 'id';
     protected $fillable = [
        'user_id',
        'qty',
          .
          .  
];

public function user()
{
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', user_id)->withDefault(['name' => 'N/A']);
}
```

But I was hoping if there was some way I can add another relationship like this?

```
public function main_user()
{
        return $this->belongsTo('App\SpecialUser', 1)->withDefault(['name' => 'N/A']);
}
```

As can be see there is no column in this table that references SpecialUser table. However, I want a specific user to be accessed on that table using relationship.

I hope I am clear enough and sorry in advance for my newb way of explaining it because I am one.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please, try this code :

```
public function mainUser()
{
        return $this->belongsTo('App\SpecialUser');
}

public function mainUserOne()
{
        return $this->mainUser()->where('id', 1);
}
```

Controller :

```
Use App\Order;

$mainUser = (new Order)->mainUserOne()->first();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, please know that I have to add these relationships to a different file. It is not in App\User.php file.

Comment: can you show me by edit your question ? for more clearly

Comment: I have edited my original question. Is it clear now?

Comment: and please use naming convention